# Python: Call derived class method from another class

Tags: python, class, derived

I have searched all the related this stackoverflow question but its not satisfied my issue.

BaseHandler.py

```py
class BaseHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, rHandler, path, param):
            self._rHandler = rHandler
            self._server = self._rHandler.server
            self._path = path
            self._param = param

    def _getElement(self, name):
        return name + "append"
```

MyClass.py

```py
class MyClass(BaseHandler.BaseHandler):

    def getA(self):
        print "Some info"

    def getB(self):
        el = self._getElement("T") #baseclass method
        print ebl
```

I wanted to call getB from the below class.

RThread.py

```py
import MyClass
class RThread(object):

    def someMethod(self):
        clr = MyClass.MyClass
        clr.getB()
```

I am getting the following error:

> ```
> TypeError: unbound method getB() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
> ```

When I try the following:

```
clr = MyClass.MyClass()
```

I am getting the following error:

> **init**() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

So kindly help me how to call this method from different class.

Comment: is your indentation correct? from the looks of it you don't have anything in any of the classes

Comment: You're on the right track: you just need a valid instance of `MyClass` first. Since `MyClass` doesn't override `__init__`, look at `BaseHandler.__init__` to see what arguments are expected.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma sorry, my indentation was not correct. I am bad in writing script on stackoverflow.

Comment: @chepner baseHandler is also a derived class of Base class (and go on). BaseHandler's one of the arguement is from Base class. How to handle this?

Comment: The type signature of `BaseHandler.__init__` is the only thing that matters for your purposes. What it does with its arguments is its own business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the class in order to call a method on it.

```py
def someMethod(self):
    clr = MyClass.MyClass(*args)
    clr.getB()
```

In the case you want the method to be callable from the class you need to use either `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`

```py
@staticmethod
def getB():
    return self._getElement("T")
```

However, you are using the `self.` notation which requires an instance. So you would need to flag the `_getElement` method with `@staticmethod` as well. Static methods do not have access to the parent class. You can use the `@classmethod` decorator to do so.

```py
@classmethod
def getB(cls):
    return cls._getElement("T")
```

Comment: Bit of a nitpick, but having a parameter named `self` doesn't mean you need to have an instance - there is nothing special about the name `self`, it is just conventional to use it to bind the instance in a method.

Comment: @JBGreen Having a parameter called "self" doesn't make that parameter refer to the instance, but the instance IS bound to the first argument of a (normal) method when called (via the instance). Assuming normal usage, it *will be* the instance regardless of what you name the parameter. You're correct that the identifier is "self" by convention.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the method correctly; you need to create an object. This is how you create an object, which is what you were doing, except you weren't passing in enough parameters.

```
clr = MyClass.MyClass()
```

Since `MyClass` inherits from `BaseHandler` and you did not override its constructor, you're using the constructor from `BaseHandler`, which has four arguments, one of which is `self`.

```
def __init__(self, rHandler, path, param):
    ...
```

So, try something like this:

```
clr = MyClass.MyClass(arg1, arg2, arg3)
clr.getB()
```